# Why EIP 2 is accepted as of 2 June 2016. But not yet finalized?

Tags: homestead, eip

My understanding is that EIP2 is implemented in [Geth 1.3.4](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/releases/tag/v1.3.4) and active since the Homestead hard fork, but it's EIP status is only 'accepted' not 'final'. Is this pure sloppiness or did I miss something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is finalized now. https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/pull/112

I think nobody noticed. :-)